# Split Order with two different shipping method in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multishipping, order-splitting

I am using Magento2. I want to do with Split Order with two different Shipping Methods.

Buyers should select two shipping methods.

One should be comes from **External API** and other should comes from **Magento admin**

How can I achieve this??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using Multi shipping addresses checkout?

Comment: No, we are using single address only, but the same address for two order should come. Only this is we need to achieve here is "two different Shipping Methods" so buyers should select two shipping methods.